# What is the easiest way to loop through a folder of files in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, file-io, filesystems

I trying to write a program that navigates the local file system using a config file containing relevant filepaths. My question is this: What are the best practices to use when performing file I/O (this will be from the desktop app to a server and back) and file system navigation in C#?

I know how to google, and I have found several solutions, but I would like to know which of the various functions is most robust and flexible. As well, if anyone has any tips regarding exception handling for C# file I/O that would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need a separate library, use the classes in the `System.IO` namespace like `File`, `FileInfo`, `Directory`, `DirectoryInfo`. A simple example:

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
foreach(FileInfo fi in d.GetFiles())
    Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
```

Comment: Sorry, again, new to C#. I meant that I have found multiple techniques, but it does appear that the methods for them are all contained in System.IO.File class.

Comment: @badpanda: Which class/method you select depends on the specifics of what you are trying to do. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Sure. I need to read in files to be sent to a web service later. These will most likely be infopath files.

Comment: I'll also need some information from the file properties, if that is relevant.

Comment: See http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-attributes/ for an example of accessing attributes.

Answer (score 3):

What various libraries are you talking about?

I would pretty much stick to `System.IO.Directory` and such.  It has everything you need.

Something like:

```
foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Yourpath"))
{
    // Do ya thang.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various classes you can use in the `System.IO` namespace, including `File`, `FileInfo`, `Directory`, and `DirectoryInfo`.

As for practices... as with any IO, make sure you close any streams you open. You also may need to utilize a `Disposable` object, so look into the `using` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`System.IO` is all you need :)

As regards exception handling. Unless we are *expecting* an exception, we should never catch it. Truly unexpected exceptions should go unhandled. [looks guilty] ok, the only exception is at the highest level, and *only* for reporting purposes, such as

```
// assuming console program, but every application Console, WinForm,
// Wpf, WindowsService, WebService, WcfService has a similar entry point
class Program
{
    // assume log4net logging here, but could as easily be
    // Console.WriteLine, or hand rolled logger
    private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger (typeof (Program));

    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
            CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException (
        object sender, 
        UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        _log.
            Fatal (
            string.Format (
            "Unhandled exception caught by " +
            "'CurrentDomain_UnhandledException'. Terminating program.", 
            e.ExceptionObject);
    }

}
```

If you are expecting an exception then one of the following is acceptable

```
// example of first option. this applies ONLY when there is a
// well-defined negative path or recovery scenario
public void SomeFunction ()
{
    try
    {
        string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText ();
    }

    // catch ONLY those exceptions you expect
    catch (System.ArgumentException e)
    {
        // ALWAYS log an error, expected or otherwise.
        _log.Warn ("Argument exception in SomeFunction", e);

        // if the use-case\control flow is recoverable, invoke
        // recovery logic, preferably out of try-catch scope
    }
}
```

or

```
// example of second option. this applies ONLY when there is no
// well defined negative path and we require additional information
// on failure
public void SomeFunction ()
{
    try
    {
        string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText ();
    }

    // catch ONLY those exceptions you expect
    catch (System.ArgumentException innerException)
    {
         // do whatever you need to do to identify this
         // problem area and provide additional context
         // like parameters or what have you. ALWAYS
         // provide inner exception
         throw new SomeCustomException (
             "some new message with extra info.",
             maybeSomeAdditionalContext,
             innerException);

         // no requirement to log, assume caller will
         // handle appropriately
    }
}
```