# SQL Server to check for files in directory

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if it is possible for SQL Server to check a directory for files and run a stored procedure. I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315732/how-can-i-a-sql-server-agent-job-if-a-file-exists-in-a-server-folder), but I am wondering if there is a way to do what I want WITHOUT SSIS.

EDIT: After reading my post, I realized I should have been more specific. Is there a way to AUTOMATICALLY or set SQL Server to check for files in a directory and run a stored procedure?

Comment: Why not use Powershell or C# to do this?

Comment: I am looking at options... if i were to use C#, how would you approach this?

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960/how-to-find-out-if-a-file-exists-in-c-sharp-net or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998384/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-folder-of-files-in-c and then this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37252.c-timer-schedule-a-task.aspx It's not really SQL Server's job to do what you're asking, but you can certainly call stored procedures from C#

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to run file related commands. To get a directly listing:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir *.csv';
```

You can also use [`bulk insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to load a file from disk into a table and take actions based on the loaded contents.

Normally you'd use the [File Watcher Task](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/File-Watcher-Task.aspx) with SSIS. But you can also use [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-schedule?view=sql-server-2017) to schedule a task for periodic execution, schedule a task with [Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx), or configure a stored procedure to runs at startup with `sp_procoption` that pauses (using [`waitfor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) between processing times.

Comment: i guess i should be more specific.. is there a way to automatically set sql server to check a directory and run a stored procedure?

Comment: Outside of SSIS, you can schedule a script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

for SQL2017 + :

```
sys.dm_os_enumerate_filesystem('C:\', '*')
```

OR

```
DECLARE @LatestBackupFile VARCHAR(255)
    SELECT TOP 1 @LatestBackupFile = fl.file_or_directory_name
    FROM sys.dm_os_enumerate_filesystem(@BackupFolder, @FullBackupFilePattern) fl
    WHERE creation_time >= @LastRestoreEnd 
    ORDER BY creation_time DESC
```

where @BackupFolder - folder, and @FullBackupFilePattern = 'WideWorldImportersbackups*.bak'

see more at
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4046638-add-the-ability-to-disable-or-enable-a-few-new-dmvs-and-dmfs-introduced-in-sql-server-2017-05d709c5-4522-3168-2cb1-f755fddff9e7

and at https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/07/sql-server-2017-less-xp_cmdshell/